# minimum value in a row with some columns

Tags: r

Let's say I have some numbers as follows:

```
ID  K1  K2  K3   K4   K5
1  0.1 0.2 0.15 0.25  0.35
```

I want to get the minimum value from columns K1, K2, K4 and K5.
I know how to get minimum value for all values in a row:

```
apply(my.matrix, 1, FUN = function(x) {min(x[x > 0])})
```

But, I don't know how to extend that statement so that I could exclude one column and get the minimum with remaining columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmin` after converting to `data.frame`

```
 do.call(pmin, c(as.data.frame(my.matrix[,c('K1', 'K2', 'K4', 'K5')]),
                 list(na.rm=TRUE)))
```

---

Or use `rowMins` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMins(my.matrix[,c('K1', 'K2', 'K4', 'K5')], na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
my.matrix <- matrix(sample(c(1:9, NA), 4*10, replace=TRUE), 
   ncol=10, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('K', 1:10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use apply over a subset of the matrix.

```
apply(my.matrix[,c(2,3,5,6)],1,min)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reshaping:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  gather(K_number, K, K1:K5) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(K_number != "K3") %>%
  filter(K == min(K) ) %>%
  right_join(data)
```